# Installing Git/TortoiseGit in existing Web Development Environment

Tags: windows, git, version-control, tortoisegit

Situation:

Web Application, 1 developer. Staging environment in one folder, production environment in another folder, on the same web server (for now). Have a need to implement source control. Windows-based.

Example file structure:

```
E:/wwwroot/app/

E:/wwwroot/app_stage/
```

Currently, changes are made in app_stage, tested, verified, and copied to production (app) manually.

I am having trouble finding documentation regarding installing TortoiseGit in such an environment.

Many thanks,
AJ

Comment: I'd suggest to create two local copies of the same Git repository (but of different branches) inside your `wwwroot/ folder`. The first would be a folder called `app_stage/` representing a Git branch containing your untested modifications, the other would be a folder called `app/` representing a Git branch containing your production application. When your app_stage version is OK, you just have to merge the app_stage branch with the production branch. Then restart a new app_stage branch based on the new production branch you just merged. I would draw something to be clearer but I can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, initialize a new git repository in the folder where you do your development:

```
cd wwwroot/app_stage
git init 
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

Now you're using git. I'd make the production folder a separate git repository so you can pull changes from the stage folder with `git pull`.

```
cd wwwroot/app
git init
git remote add stage /e/wwwroot/app_stage/.git
```

Instead of copying files from app_stage to app, pull them with git:

```
git pull stage
```

Comment: Looking forward to trying this solution early next week. One follow up question, when making code changes to app_stage after initializing git, do i need to explicitly checkout/checkin files, or can i just edit them and pull them from stage to production? Especially since i am the lone developer.

Comment: You should read a little more about git to get comfortable with it. gitimmersion.com is a great resource. You don't check files out, but you do commit changes. In general, make whatever changes you want in app_stage and when you're happy, commit them. Make as many commits as you want - you won't affect prod. When you are ready to get the changes on prod, git pull will get everything that has been committed.